# Multiple contexts per thread

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework

Is it safe to create multiple Context in one thread to save the data in the web application ?
I've got the code like below and worry if it would work on big amount of iterations.
Is there any problems with such code ?

```
    private void SaveContent(TargetSegment ts,
                                   Folder f,
                                   IEnumerable<Module> m)
    {
        using(var ctx = new EntityContainer())
        {
            var entity = CreateEntityFrom(ts, f, m);

            ctx.Entities.Add(entity);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        } 
    }

    foreach(var ts in TargetSegments)
    {
        var f = FindFolder(ts);
        var m = ExtractModules(ts, f);

        SaveContent(ts, f, m);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your code.  This above code will execute a SQL INSERT statement each time it is called.  You have your code in a using block, which is the best way to dispose of the object.

I've run into performance issues only when selecting from an EF model for multiple transactions; and in that case, I cached whenever possible and have had no problems.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use single SaveChanges call for all sequence, but it is difficult to validate each entity when in is going to be written to db. So, I handle the exception when I have all info about the error and it's context.